# How can I invoke an Azure Data Factory pipeline from C# code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I need some ideas for invoking an ADF (Azure Data Factory) job from C# code. If you can share some examples implementing this, it will really be helpful.

Thank you for looking into my post.

Answer (score 12):

Install the latest version of the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory` NuGet package. Then you can trigger an ADF pipeline like this:

```
private DataFactoryManagementClient CreateClient(string subscriptionId, string tenantId)
    {
        // AzureServiceTokenProvider uses developer credentials when running locally
        // and uses managed identity when deployed to Azure.
        // If getting an exception when running locally, run "az login" command in Azure CLI
        var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var token = provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com", tenantId).Result;
        ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

        DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials);
        client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        return client;
    }

    public async Task<string> TriggerPipeline(string pipelineName, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        var run = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, parameters: parameters);
        return run.Body.RunId;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Connell.O'Donnell. I'll try this code and let you know if I need any further help. Really appreciate your quick help.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.