# Call Execute SSIS Package Activity Programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

We have an on-prem solution that creates a .dtsx package via C#. All the connection managers, events, are defined via code as well. In the end it calls the DTSExecResult Execute(...) method from the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime assembly to run the package. This solution has been working well for us, but with most of our applications migrated in Azure, we're now having the need to utilize Azure Data Factory for executing these packages moving forward.

I've been reading up and it looks like what we need is somewhere along the lines of the [Package location: File system (Package)] or the [Package location: Embedded package] section from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity?tabs=data-factory

Is there a way to call said activity via code? The idea being that we pass the UNC path of the .dtsx package created by our code as well as other required parameters that we may need to tweak for every .dtsx we want to run through it, then invoke or run the pipeline similar to the solution provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865325/1227893

Comment: Can you explain what specific issue you are having with `DTSExecResult Execute(...)` method when you're using SSIS in data factory? Is it that you don't know the .dtsx file path? By the looks of that link you need to upload it to blob storage.

Comment: Hi Nick. No issues with it for dealing with on-prem. Our hope is that we can just tweak our code to call the Execute SSIS Data package activity, feed it with the UNC path of the DTSX file we want it to run, and then trigger the execution of the said activity. If that is not possible, we're open to potentially utilizing an SSISDB where we deploy and run the DTSX, but wanted to explore the possibility first of modifying and executing package activity through code, if at all possible.

Comment: This indicates that a package saved in blob can be accessed via a UNC, if you use _Azure Files_ which is a type of API against blob storage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity?tabs=data-factory#package-location-file-system-package. I suggest you experiment with this. I imagine everything that you see in the dialog would need to be provided in your C# code. This could be tricky, particularly if you are using windows authentication.

Comment: I have to say that the solution you describe sounds a bit over engineered. You could just build a data integration directly in C# for example. If your data integrations need to be programatically generated, native Azure Data Factory actually has a lot of capability to do things like auto mapping that SSIS can't do. In my opinion you are taking legacy ETL approaches and trying to squash them into cloud, and that will just introduce technical debt. But I understand that this is how most enterprises operate!